# Вставка текста в PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, .net

Имеется шаблонный PDF - документ, представляющий собой бланк формы для заполнения. Заполняемые поля представляют собой длинные ряды квадратов. В каждый из квадратов вписывается тот или иной символ. Нужно каким-то образом заполнить данную форму автоматически. Есть ли какие-то библиотеки (желательно .net ),  позволяющие это делать. 
То есть интересует не просто вставка текста в PDF - документ, а именно вставка каждого символа в отдельный заполнитель, что является несколько более сложной задачей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я использую для этих целей библиотеку [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/). В ней есть все необходимые средства для заполнения шаблонного PDF документа.

Comment: большое спасибо, но я уже решил проблему как раз с помощью этой библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, здесь проще создать свой "алфавит". То есть набор картинок, где есть изображение каждого символа в этом квадратике. И "печатать" в файл набором этих картинок. Ну этот вариант поможет, если не требуется дальнейшее редактирование этой формы.

Comment: возможно, это имеет смысл, но тогда могут появиться видимые границы на стыке картинки и документа. Дело в том, что документ должен быть перенаправлен в одну важную и очень бюрократическую госорганизацию,  в которой он может быть не принят в таком случае

Comment: Ну так сделать фон этой картинки точно в фон документа и сделать их такими, что бы их можно было печатать без отступов (вплотную друг к другу). Ну и сделать потом документ только для чтения - то есть превратить его полностью в картинку. И никто и никогда не поймет как он был создан :D 
Ну или совсем для извращенцев - так после такой печати пройтись по нему файнридером и готово )))))

Comment: файнридер вряд ли прокатит - генерация таких документов должна быть  чуть ли не в промышленном масштабе, порядка десятка за раз

Comment: Тогда, если вариант с картинками не подходит, я думаю нужно капать в корень этого документа. Может там у каждого такого "поля для ввода" есть какой нибудь ID или что то вроде этого. Если эти элементы никак не пронумерованы, да и вообще безадресные, тогда боюсь ничего не выйдет. 

Как вариант можно попробовать вместо картинок, как я предлагал, создать свой шрифт с отступами побольше и где каждая буква будет в своем... ну а дальше вы уже поняли ;-)